Question about HomePod surface mesh
Probably a silly question, but I was trying to attach the power cord to my new (full-size) HomePod and for a minute I didn't realise that the plug that enters the HomePod had to be flipped the other way around.  So for a few seconds I applied some pressure to the HomePod, so that my fingers that were holding the HomePod sunk in a tiny bit (4mm / 1/8" ? ) into the mesh. That is, the surface is simply slightly squishy.  I have a HomePod Mini and the mesh surface is quite solid. I was just wondering if there might be a speaker right underneath -- that is, the surface mesh was similar to the covering for a speaker cone -- or something else delicate.  All seems well, and there are no surface marks or deformations or anything, and it was just a little squishiness under finger pressure, a few millimetres or so.

They are squishy and there are speakers behind the mesh but I believe they are half an inch or more offset behind the frame.
I try not to lift or squish them but believe you’d have to really squeeze to deform the solid plastic covering the tweeters.
You can see this in the middle photo on step 12 of this iFixit tear down

https://ifixit.com/teardown/homepod+teardown/103133

I don’t think you can poke any of the tweeters / midrange or the sub woofer without an inch or more intrusion under the mesh.

Thanks -- I also took a look at another (less professional) video, where they took one apart.  The speakers are all concealed inside the plastic frame?  That is, one can't get to them directly through the mesh.  Or am I wrong?  I know (now) that there are like 7 speakers inside the frame at the bottom, and a subwoofer on top.  But the subwoofer is also inside the plastic casing?

You should be good as long as you didn’t go in an entire inch or several cm.
